# BankAccount problem and Threads, please help

Tags: java, multithreading

I have been working on 2.4 and am having trouble getting the program to work correctly with out throw a null pointer exception because it can not get the account number of the source and destination. Now I am running the program with 50 transactions, but the more I use the more null pointer exceptions appear, if you can guide me to the right path that would be great. The code is posted below.

Here is a sample of the output.

```
Withdrawing 592.5 from account 3
Balance is: 9339.92
Balance is: 9339.92
Withdrawing 496.81 from account 7
Withdrawing 233.86 from account 2
Balance is: 9339.92
Withdrawing 366.35 from account 5
Depositing 366.35 from account 6
Transfer occuring from 5 to 6 done.
Depositing 32.8 from account 6
Depositing 911.01 from account 8
Transfer occuring from 1 to 8
Withdrawing 601.23 from account 1
Depositing 601.23 from account 8
Transfer occuring from 1 to 8 done.
Withdrawing 115.42 from account 8
Transfer occuring from 8 to 5
Withdrawing 886.08 from account 8
Depositing 886.08 from account 5
Transfer occuring from 8 to 5 done.
Transfer occuring from 8 to 9
Withdrawing 820.83 from account 8
Transfer occuring from 5 to 7
Withdrawing 50.96 from account 5
Depositing 50.96 from account 7
Transfer occuring from 5 to 7 done.
Balance is: 8738.69
Exception in thread "Thread-43" Depositing 820.83 from account 9
Transfer occuring from 8 to 9 done.
[b]java.lang.NullPointerException
    at OrderedTeller.transfer(OrderedTeller.java:54)
    at OrderedTeller.run(OrderedTeller.java:29)[/b]
Withdrawing 361.35 from account 2
Depositing 472.04 from account 9
Balance is: 9452.789999999999
Transfer occuring from 1 to 2
Withdrawing 255.33 from account 1
Depositing 255.33 from account 2
Transfer occuring from 1 to 2 done.
Depositing 359.63 from account 2
Depositing 880.57 from account 6
Depositing 734.09 from account 7
Withdrawing 210.11 from account 4
Depositing 640.98 from account 5
Withdrawing 172.63 from account 5
```

Code:

```
public class Bank {

    private List<BankAccount> bankAccounts = new ArrayList<BankAccount>();

    public Bank() {


    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        bankAccounts.add(new BankAccount(i, 10000.00));
    }

    doTransActions("Transactions.txt");

    }

    public void doTransActions(String fileName) {
    BufferedReader in = null;
    try {
        String strLine = null;
        in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        int distinationAccount = 0;
        int sourceAccount = 0;
        double amount = 0;

        while ((strLine = in.readLine()) != null) {

        java.lang.String[] tokens = strLine.split("[%]");
        String transaction = tokens[0];

        if (transaction.equals("TRANSFER")) {


            sourceAccount = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            distinationAccount = Integer.parseInt(tokens[2]);
            amount = Double.parseDouble(tokens[3]);

            BankAccount source = null;
            BankAccount distination = null;
            for (BankAccount account : bankAccounts) {

            if (account.getNumber() == sourceAccount) {

                source = account;


            }
            if (account.getNumber() == distinationAccount) {

                distination = account;


            }
            }

            new OrderedTeller(source, distination, transaction, amount).start();

        } else {

            sourceAccount = Integer.parseInt(tokens[1]);
            amount = Double.parseDouble(tokens[2]);

            BankAccount source = null;

            for (BankAccount account : bankAccounts) {

            if (account.getNumber() == sourceAccount) {

                source = account;

            }
            }

            new OrderedTeller(source, transaction, amount).start();

        }

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());

    } finally {
        try {
        in.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    }

}

public class OrderedTeller extends Thread {

    private BankAccount source = null, dest = null;
    private String transType = null;
    private double amount = 0;

    public OrderedTeller(BankAccount a, BankAccount b, String transType, double amount)

    {
    source = a;
    dest = b;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.transType = transType;
    }

    public OrderedTeller(BankAccount a, String transType, double amount)

    {
    source = a;
    this.amount = amount;
    this.transType = transType;
    }

    public void run() {

    if (transType.equals("TRANSFER")) {

        transfer(amount);

    } else if (transType.equals("WITHDRAW")) {

        source.withdraw(amount);


    } else if (transType.equals("DEPOSIT")) {

        source.deposit(amount);

    } else if (transType.equals("BALANCE")) {

        System.out.println("Balance is: "+source.getBalance());

    } else {

        System.out.println("ERROR: TRANSACTION TYPE NOT RECOGNIZED");
    }
    }

    public void transfer(double amount) {

    BankAccount first, second;

    if (source.getNumber() < dest.getNumber()) {
        first = source;
        second = dest;
    } else {
        first = dest;
        second = source;
    }
    synchronized (first) {
        Thread.yield();
        synchronized (second) {
        System.out.println("Transfer occuring from " + source.getNumber() + " to " + dest.getNumber());
        source.withdraw(amount);
        dest.deposit(amount);
        System.out.println("Transfer occuring from " + source.getNumber() + " to " + dest.getNumber()+ " done.");
        }
    }
    }
}

public class BankAccount {

    private double balance = 0;
    private int number = 0;

    public BankAccount(int number, double initialBalance) {
    this.number = number;
    balance = initialBalance;
    }

    public int getNumber() {

    return number;
    }

    public double getBalance() {

    return balance;
    }

    public synchronized void deposit(double amount) {

    double prevBalance = balance;
    System.out.println("Depositing " + amount + " from account " + number);
    balance = prevBalance + amount;
    }

    public synchronized void withdraw(double amount) {

    double prevBalance = balance;
    System.out.println("Withdrawing " + amount + " from account " + number);
    balance = prevBalance - amount;
    }

}
```

This is the text file I read the transactions from
Each line starts with a transaction in the real text file.

```
TRANSFER%4%3%866.85
TRANSFER%2%7%861.79
BALANCE%9%895.41
DEPOSIT%7%475.82
WITHDRAW%3%845.92
WITHDRAW%4%766.69
BALANCE%10%591.67
DEPOSIT%8%12.22
TRANSFER%3%6%57.45
BALANCE%10%417.84
TRANSFER%10%8%928.33
TRANSFER%9%7%94.46
WITHDRAW%5%874.17
DEPOSIT%9%538.37
BALANCE%9%324.88
TRANSFER%6%7%773.23
DEPOSIT%3%81.81
BALANCE%8%564.51
TRANSFER%6%2%300.17
TRANSFER%5%6%366.35
DEPOSIT%10%627.87
DEPOSIT%8%911.01
TRANSFER%1%2%535.72
TRANSFER%1%8%601.23
TRANSFER%1%6%124.36
WITHDRAW%8%115.42
BALANCE%3%942.87
TRANSFER%8%5%886.08
DEPOSIT%7%604.41
WITHDRAW%2%361.35
WITHDRAW%2%233.86
WITHDRAW%4%210.11
DEPOSIT%6%32.8
DEPOSIT%6%880.57
WITHDRAW%7%496.81
WITHDRAW%5%172.63
BALANCE%1%70.4
DEPOSIT%7%734.09
BALANCE%1%274.6
DEPOSIT%5%640.98
WITHDRAW%3%592.5
DEPOSIT%9%472.04
BALANCE%1%647.71
TRANSFER%3%10%537.52
BALANCE%1%461.09
BALANCE%3%172.58
TRANSFER%8%9%820.83
TRANSFER%1%2%255.33
TRANSFER%5%7%50.96
DEPOSIT%2%359.63
```

Comment: I've (at least partially) formatted the code (and text), but I've got to say that I kind of doubt it'll do a lot of good. You really need to narrow your problem down to a bit more reasonable-sized chunk of code before most people are going to work very hard at helping diagnose your problem.

Comment: to add to what Jerry said, there's no point increasing the no. of transactions and be bothered about the increased occurrence of NPE. first up, find the smallest number of transactions which lead to an NPE, then determine the flow of things, and then post-in your findings.

Comment: Sounds like a good time to use the debugger.  You should be able to trap the NullPointerException and see what it is doing when this happens.

Answer (score 3):

It would appear that the account numbers in your file are 1-based, whereas the accounts you're generating are zero based. As such, when it tries to do an action involving account #10 in the file, it'll fail to set either source or destination, and you get the null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

If I had to guess, I'd say you're calling run() on an OrderedTeller that has been constructed with the wrong constructor, since only one of them initializes the source and destination.  In order to simplify things.

If it's not that, try sticking something into the constructor that throws an exception if it's initialized with null sources and destinations.  That way you can find the location of the actual source of your problem: initializing the object incorrectly.